# RequireJS loading dependencies inconsistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

I have a jQuery plugin that is dependent on jQuery being loaded first. I'm using [`shim`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) and [`require([])`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-deps) to ensure that jQuery is loaded first.
Sometimes the app works, but usually it doesn't and gives me the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'noUiSlider'`

...which is indicative of jQuery not being loaded first. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my app's main script:

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "app/",
    "paths": {
        "app": "./app",
        "threejs" : "../lib/three.min",
        "jquery" : "../lib/jquery",
        "jquery.nouislider.min": "../lib/jquery.nouislider.min"
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery.nouislider.min": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            init: function($) {
                return this;
            }
        }
    }
});

require([
    "jquery",
    "jquery.nouislider.min",
    "threejs",
    "Scene"
],
function ($) {
    var glScene = new Scene();
    glScene.clockStart();

    $(function(){
        var slider = $("<div></div>");
        slider.attr("id", "sample-minimal");
        $("body").append(slider);
        $("#sample-minimal").noUiSlider({
             range: [0, 100]
            ,start: [20, 80]
            ,connect: true
        });
    });

    function onWindowResize(event) {
        glScene.windowResize();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you think, that error, you provided, indicates that jQuery doesn't load first? Doesn't a fact, that `$(function(){` works properly proves opposite?

Anyway, try this:

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "app/",
    "paths": {
        "app": "./app",
        "threejs" : "../lib/three.min",
        "jquery" : "../lib/jquery",
        "jquery.nouislider.min": "../lib/jquery.nouislider.min"
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery.nouislider.min": {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});

require([
    "jquery.nouislider.min",
    "threejs",
    "Scene"
],
function ($) {
    var glScene = new Scene();
    glScene.clockStart();

    $(function(){
        var slider = $("<div></div>");
        slider.attr("id", "sample-minimal");
        $("body").append(slider);
        $("#sample-minimal").noUiSlider({
             range: [0, 100]
            ,start: [20, 80]
            ,connect: true
        });
    });

    function onWindowResize(event) {
        glScene.windowResize();
    }
});
```

**Update 1: Basic example:**

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="./jquery.nouislider.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="stage"></div>
        <script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        jquery : 'jquery-2.0.3',
        'jquery.nouislider' : 'jquery.nouislider'
    },
    shim : {
        'jquery.nouislider' : {deps : ['jquery'], exports : '$'}
    }
});

require(['jquery.nouislider'], function($) {
    $(function(){
        $("#stage").noUiSlider({
             range: [0, 100]
            ,start: [20, 80]
            ,connect: true
        });
    });
});
```

**Update2: Priority option:**

Also, you may want to use priority option:

> priority: An array of module/file names to load immediately, before
>   tracing down any other dependencies. This allows you to set up a small
>   set of files that are downloaded in parallel that contain most of the
>   modules and their dependencies already built in. More information is
>   in the Optimization FAQ, Priority Downloads.Note: resources loaded by
>   loader plugins (like 'text!template.html') cannot be specified in the
>   priority array: the priority mechanism only works with regular
>   JavaScript resources.

it should be used like this:

```
paths : {
   ....
},
shim : {
   ....
},
priority : ['jquery']
```

Comment: The problem isn't that jQuery doesn't load at all. The problem is that the plugin loads before jQuery loads. Keep in mind that the problem is intermittent (i.e., sometimes it works, and sometimes it does not).

Comment: @josh See an updated example. This one works just fine.

Comment: @AndrewShustariov I have similar problem. Would you mind connecting with teamviewer to help me debug and I can pay you for your time?

Answer (score 1):

You're using RequireJS 1.x. Solution: Upgrade to 2.x.

Evidence that you're using 1.x: If setting `priority` did the trick (as you wrote in a comment on the other answer) that's evidence that you are using version 1.0 because `priority` was [removed from the 2.x series](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0#wiki-removed).

Moreover, `shim` was [introduced with 2.x](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0) so, since you are using a 1.x version, your `shim` config was just ignored by RequireJS. This explains the erratic behavior you were experiencing, your `shim` was ignored, which means that `jquery` and `jquery.nouislider.min` could load in any order. The shim you have looks fine as it is. It was just ignored!